# Four questions - Calculator Application - Android Java

Tags: java, android, math, variables

Hey all, I am a total newbie developing an android application, I've been reading 'Sams Teach Yourself Java in 24 hours' and it's a great book. But I have been stuck on a bit where I get the value of a decimal number only editTexts and use java maths to work out my end value.

1. Is there a way to have an editText input straight to a float or double variable rather than to a string and then from a string to a double?
2. Are there any real issues with converting between a string and a double or float or will the values remain the same and not be polluted.
3. Differences / pros and cons of using a doble as opposed to a float.
4. Best way to input a fraction value from the user?

Thanks for any help. Have a good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No.  You could write your own subclass that makes it seem like that is what's happening, but at some point somewhere in the chain you have to do a conversion from character/text data to numerical data.
2. Yes.  Primitive floating-point types use [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) to encode decimal numbers in binary.  The encoding provides very good precision, but it is not exact/cannot exactly represent many possible numbers.  So if you parse from a string to a primitive floating-point type, and then back to string again, you may get something that is different from your input string.
3. A double uses twice as many bits to encode the number as a float, and thus is able to maintain a greater degree of precision.  It will not, however, remove the issues discussed in #2.  If you want to remove those issues, consider using something like `BigDecimal` to represent your numbers instead of primitive types like `float` or `double`.
4. Read the whole thing as a string, `split()` it on the '/' character, and then store each part as an integer (or `BigInteger`).  If you need to display it as a decimal, use `BigDecimal` to perform the division.

Answer (score 4):

1. No, you can't.
2. Yes.  If your string is, say, an ID and reads like "0029482", after you turn it into an integer it will read "29482" and probably will be invalid.  Strings can be longer than doubles or floats, and if you have a value like "0.12345678901234567890123456789" in a string, you will lose a lot of precision by converting that to a double.
3. Doubles use double the number of bits (hence the name), and can therefore hold more precision.
4. Accept the denominator and numerator integers, and store them in a custom class.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to add that if you are looking for an alternative to `double` or `float` that doesn't entail loss of precision when converting between strings and numeric form, look at these:

- The standard [`java.math.BigDecimal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class represents an arbitrary precision scaled number; i.e. an arbitrary precision integer multiplied (scaled) by a fixed integer power of 10.
- The Apache [`dfp`](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/dfp/package-summary.html) package contains implementations of decimal-based floating numbers.

However, I'd steer clear of both of this topic for now, and implement using `float` or `double`.  (I take it that your *real* aim is to learn how to write Java, not to build the world's greatest calculator app.)